# return data from json file if another one is not exist

Tags: python, json, openstreetmap

I'm trying to return data to Django model, from Overpass API JSON data after downloaded

```py
"elements": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 662934404,
  "lat": 35.572157,
  "lon": 45.3898839,
  "tags": {
    "addr:postcode": "46001",
    "name": "City Center",
    "name:en": "City Center Mall",
    "name:ku": "City Center Mall",
    "shop": "mall",
    "website": "http://www.citycentersul.com"
  }
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 2413990402,
  "lat": 35.5014386,
  "lon": 45.4457576,
  "tags": {
    "addr:city": "sulaymaniyah",
    "designation": "ASSAN",
    "name": "ASSAN STEEL CO.",
    "opening_hours": "3 min",
    "shop": "doityourself",
    "source": "ASSAN Steel Company General  Trading  Co, Ltd"
  },
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 2414374708,
  "lat": 35.506121,
  "lon": 45.4417229,
  "tags": {
    "addr:city": "sulaymaniyah",
    "name:ku": "ASSAN Steel Company General Trading Co, Ltd",
    "shop": "doityourself",
  }
},
```

but some of the data dosent have both of them together `name , name:ku ,name:en`
so what should i do if name is none then return name:ku ,  if its exists then name:en

i've tried this but doesnt work

```py
with open('data.json') as datafile:
    objects = json.load(datafile)
    for obj in objects['elements']:
        try:
            objType = obj['type']
            if objType == 'node':
                tags = obj['tags']
                name = tags.get('name')
                if not name:
                    name = tags.get('name:en')
                elif not name:
                    name = tags.get('name:ku')
                elif not name:
                    name = tags.get('name:ar')
                else:
                    name = tags.get('shop','no-name')
```

is there something else I've missed?
thanks for helping

Comment: *doesn't work* means nothing. Please say what happens: error (and what is the stacktrace), wrong output (show actual and expected output) or...?

Comment: @SergeBallesta i tried to add the name to a django model , and name field in django is required , and when i try to migrate , it says name is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over all possible keys and stop after a value was detected:

```
with open('data.json') as datafile:
objects = json.load(datafile)
for obj in objects['elements']:
    objType = obj['type']
    if objType == 'node':
        tags = obj['tags']

        name = None
        for nameId in ('name', 'name:en', 'name:ku', 'name:ar'):
            if nameId in tags:
                name = tags[name]
                break # stop looping, we got a name value

        # Set default if no key was found
        if not name:
            name = tags.get('shop','no-name')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following and all subsequent `elif`-conditions are wrong:

```
name = tags.get('name')
if not name:
    name = tags.get('name:en')
elif not name:
    name = tags.get('name:ku')
```

`elif` applies to all previous conditions and gets only executed if all of the previous conditions evaluated to `false`. In your case, however, the first if-condition (`if not name`) already evaluated to `true`. Therefore your `elif`-conditions won't get executed. You need to change them to `if`-conditions instead:

```
name = tags.get('name')
if not name:
    name = tags.get('name:en')
if not name:
    name = tags.get('name:ku')
if not name:
    name = tags.get('name:ar')
if not name:
    name = tags.get('shop','no-name')
```

The `loop`-approach suggested by Maurice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60810856/1340631 is better, though.